# Asp.net MVC with Entity, using jquery to pass data into List. Does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, editortemplates

**Edit 3 / Final**

This is the fully working example using .NET MVC, Jquery and editor templates.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4yxbhkuowyd7va/exerciseTest.rar

**Edit 2**

It finally works ! Thanks to the answer below. It appears that i needed to change the NewAnswerRow partial line:

```
<input type='text' id='Answers_@(Model.AnswerId)__Answer'   name='Answers[@Model.AnswerId].Answer'/>
```

Thanks !

**Edit 1:**

I've followed this guide:
http://www.techiesweb.net/asp-net-mvc3-dynamically-added-form-fields-model-binding/

The funny part is, that when I use his source, it works like it should. But it is almost exactly the same.

**Original Post**

First off all thanks for reading this message, and willing to help. I'm flabbergasted. Let me try to explain my situation. I'm trying to create a new exercise which has a list with answers. These answers are created on the fly with Jquery. I'm reading those answers with EditorTemplates. Everything works except that when i create new 'Answer' fields and press 'Post' My controller cant see any data (answers). The weird thing is. When I use data annotations like [required] in for example an answer property. I'm getting redirected to the Index. When I try it again, my model isn't empty anymore.

So basically my question is, how can i manage to get those answers into my list?

I've created a new project for you guys to be more clear and specific.

I have 2 models,

- Exercise
- Answers

**ExerciseModel class**

```
[Table("Exercise")]
public class ExerciseModel
{

    [Key]
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }


    public string Question { get; set; }


    public IList<AnswerModel> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

It's basically a simple class. As you guys can see. There's a List with Answers.

**AnswerModel**

```
[Table("Answer")]
public class AnswerModel
{
    [Key]
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }

    public string Answer { get; set; }
 }
```

A simple AnswerModel class with an Id and an Answer.

**My Controller**

```
public class ExerciseController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataContext db = new DataContext();
    //
    // GET: /Exercise/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var exercise = new ExerciseModel();
        exercise.Answers = GetAnswers();

        return View(exercise);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ExerciseModel exercisemodel)
    {
        //need to implement interaction with database (not yet) testing phase.
        return View("PostedData", exercisemodel);
    }


    public ActionResult NewAnswersRow(int id)
    {
        var answers = new AnswerModel { AnswerId = id };
        return View("partial/NewAnswersRow", answers);
    }


    private List<AnswerModel> GetAnswers()
    {
        var answerslist = new List<AnswerModel>();
        answerslist.Add(new AnswerModel { AnswerId = 1, Answer = "This is a hardcoded answer"}); //normally db.Answers (for testing purposes)
        return answerslist;
    }

}
```

**My Index view**

```
@model exerciseTest.Models.ExerciseModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div class="divAnswers">
        <div  id="container">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question)
            </div>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Answers)

        </div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add New Item" />
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}


    <script>

$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").click(function (e) {
        var itemIndex = $("#container input.iHidden").length;
        console.debug("itemIndex : "+itemIndex);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get("@Url.Action("NewAnswersRow", "Exercise")/"+itemIndex,function(data){
            $("#container").append(data);
        });           
    });
});

</script>
```

**My editor template of AnswerModel**

```
@model exerciseTest.Models.AnswerModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<tr> 
 <td>
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AnswerId, new { @class="iHidden" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Answer) </td>
</tr>
```

**My NewAnswersRow.cshtml for creating new rows on the fly with Jquery (see Index for the code part)**

```
@model exerciseTest.Models.AnswerModel
@{    Layout = null; }
<tr> 
 <td>
  <input type="hidden" id="Answers_@(Model.AnswerId)__Id" class="iHidden"  name='Answers[@Model.AnswerId].Id' />
  <input type='text' id='Answers_@(Model.AnswerId)__AnswersText'   name='Answers[@Model.AnswerId].AnswersText'/>
 </td>
</tr>
```

**And my 'postedData' view for testing purposes**

```
@model exerciseTest.Models.ExerciseModel
<h3>Posted data is </h3>

@foreach (var item in Model.Answers)
{
   <p>@item.Answer</p>
}
```

I'm trying to get this thing to work. I must say, In like 5 years, i've never asked someting here on StackOverflow because i could find answers. But this time, I need your help.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bug in your `NewAnswersRow partial view`. `Name` and `Id` are the same in your html, however it is name that is passed in a form post. If you look at what `MVC` is doing, the name attribute of the answer text field is `Answers[x].Answer`, while the `Id` is `Answers[x].AnswerText`.

So change your `name='Answers[@Model.AnswerId].AnswerText'` to `name='Answers[@Model.AnswerId].Answer'` so it matches what `MVC` is expecting. Worked for me!

Comment: Thanks !! I couldn't see the problem anymore.. It is so something stupid. You're awesome.