# ASP.NET MVC, modelstate.isvalid is never valid this way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, mvc-editor-templates

I have a question for you guys. I am programming an application where I can create exercises with multiple answers. I asked something a few days ago and it completely works at this moment.

[Asp.net MVC with Entity, using jquery to pass data into List. Does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772964/asp-net-mvc-with-entity-using-jquery-to-pass-data-into-list-does-not-work)

The source is not the same anymore. I only have one question about `modelstate.isvalid`.

Let me give you guys an example. I have an `ExerciseModel` with a list Answers. Creating new answers on the fly with jQuery and `EditorTemplates` works perfect. The only thing is that validation will never work now. I want to add `modelstate.isvalid` into my `httpPost` method for validation.

The question is about Editing/creating new answers

```
public ActionResult EditQuestion(int id)
{
    ExerciseModel exercisemodel = db.Exercise.Find(id);
    if (exercisemodel == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    exercisemodel.Answers = GetAnswers(id);
    ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Course, "CourseId", "CourseName", 
                                 exercisemodel.CourseId);
    return View(exercisemodel);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditQuestion(ExerciseModel exercisemodel)
{
    foreach (var answer in exercisemodel.Answers)
    {
        db.Entry(answer).State = answer.AnswerId == 0 ?
                        EntityState.Added :
                        EntityState.Modified;
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The reason for this, is because I can create new answers while I also can edit the existing answers and add them into my list of answers in my `ExerciseModel`. So my `ExerciseModel` changes when i create new answers. That's the reason why `modelstate.isvalid` never will be true.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I assume it's just ID that fails validation?

Comment: @mattytommo Yes, exactly. Whenever I check my modelstate error. It gives me the message with; "The AnswerId is required". The ID of Answer is 0 when i create a new one. It's up to my DB to assign an ID.

Comment: In your view type @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.ID)

Comment: @AlexOvechkin He already has that (see his older question).

Comment: @mattytommo check my latest post. Indeed, i already had that, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it ! Thanks guys for your replies. Strange but it works.. I already had a hidden Id. I have a partial with just few table rows. This, for adding new answers into my existing page  with jQuery.

I had;

```
    <input type="hidden" id="Answers_@(Model.AnswerId)__Id" class="iHidden"  name='Answers[@Model.AnswerId].AnswerId' />
```

Because it creates a new row with an answer. Now I replaced it with.

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.AnswerId, new { @class = "iHidden" })
```

And it works now. Don't know why but well, razor does the job.